# Valores na busca PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho os seguintes argumentos:

```
//passo o valor para a variavel sómente se o get existir
$valor_pesquisar = isset($_GET['pesquisar'])?isset($_GET['pesquisar']):'';
if(!isset($_GET['pesquisar'])){

}else{
    $valor_pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];
}

//Selecionar todos os cursos da tabela
$result_curso = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%'";
$resultado_curso = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curso);

//Contar o total de cursos
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curso);

//Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
$quantidade_pg = 6;

//calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
$num_pagina = ceil($total_cursos/$quantidade_pg);

//Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

//Selecionar os cursos a serem apresentado na página
$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos);
```

Gostaria de saber como adicionar um `echo` quando a busca não encontrasse resultado.

Comment: Quando você diz "Não encontrasse nenhum resultado", você quer dizer se o `$_GET['pesquisar']` estiver vazio?

Comment: Não quando no caso em fizer a busca e não achar resultado na busca.

Comment: esse ai acima é oq uso para mostrar minha tabela e tbm buscar,  consigo buscar normal mas se eu busco algo que não tenho ele retorna a página vazia eu queria era colocar uma echo dizendo que não encontrou resultado.  http://imperionutry.esy.es

Comment: vlw, ja vou estudar essa parada ai agora aqui..   para não ter problemas futuros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo assim?

```
if ($total_cursos != 0) {
    // Se houver cursos, fazer ação
} else {
    // Caso contrário, echo.
    echo "Nenhum curso encontrado";
}
```

Comment: sim  mas não sei onde incremento pois nao funciona .

Comment: No final do código. Se não for pedir muito, você poderia postar a parte do código onde ele imprime os resultados?

Comment: é atraves de um While mas já acertei aqui com essa solução que me passou, po Obrigado mesmo cara tava quebrando a cabeça, fiz o site com base de estudos no youtube e estou tomando essas surras ai desculpa ai o trabalho cara.

Comment: @LéoAndrade Magina hahaha Mais uma coisa, cuida com SQL Injection. Você deve preparar a query para consulta. Se eu pesquisar por `'`, seu código retornará um erro que poderá ser usado para deletar seu banco de dados, então tome cuidado.